# How to change another pandas column using dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, replace

Here I have `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Menu':['Salad', 'Buger', 'Buger', 'Buger'], 
                    'Combo':['Salad A', 'Buger A', 'Buger B', 'Buger C'], 
                    'Status':['Regular', 'Regular', 'Regular', 'Promotion']}) 

    Menu    Combo       Status
0   Salad   Salad A     Regular
1   Buger   Buger A     Regular
2   Buger   Buger B     Regular
3   Buger   Buger C     Promotion
```

and I want to use `dic` to change `Status` based on `Combo` values. To this:

```
dic = {'Buger B': 'Promotion', 'Buger C': 'Unavailable'}

    Menu    Combo       Status
0   Salad   Salad A     Regular
1   Buger   Buger A     Regular
2   Buger   Buger B     Promotion
3   Buger   Buger C     Unavailable
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df["Status"] = df["Combo"].map(dic).fillna(df["Status"])
```

**Output:**

```
    Menu    Combo   Status
0   Salad   Salad A Regular
1   Buger   Buger A Regular
2   Buger   Buger B Promotion
3   Buger   Buger C Unavailable
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it somewhat this way. Using `itertuples()` is always advised because it's much faster way to iterate over a `pandas.DataFrame`.

```
for val in df.itertuples():
    combo_val = getattr(val, 'Combo')
    if combo_val in dic.keys():
        df.loc[val[0], 'Status'] = dic[combo_val]

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Menu    Combo       Status
0  Salad  Salad A      Regular
1  Buger  Buger A      Regular
2  Buger  Buger B    Promotion
3  Buger  Buger C  Unavailable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in dic.keys():
    df.loc[df['Combo'] == key, 'Status'] = dic[key]
```

Output:

```
    Menu    Combo       Status
0  Salad  Salad A      Regular
1  Buger  Buger A      Regular
2  Buger  Buger B    Promotion
3  Buger  Buger C  Unavailable
```